# I want to go though array and check if it matches with the values or not in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to go through an array and check if it matches value with the values of **name** in array or not and change **setFound** value to true if it **(if it matches and false if it not matches)**
But it keeps on changing state. i called function **changeState** in if condition to change state if it matches. **First thing** is that it does not check all the values in array and **Second** it keeps on changing state.

import React from 'react';

import { Paper, Typography, TextField , Button, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import {useEffect} from 'react';

const useStyle = makeStyles((theme)=>(

```
{
    formWrapper : {
        display : 'flex',
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        alignItems : 'center',
        justifyContent : 'center'
    },
    paper : {
        padding : '20px',
        margin : '20px'
    },
    textfield : {
        marginLeft : '20px',
        marginBottom : '10px'
    },
    span : {
        margin: '10px',
        marginLeft : '20px'
    }

}
```

))

const Register = () =>{

```
const classes = useStyle();
const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
const [array, setArray] = React.useState([{name : 'faateh', password : 'pass'},{name : 'Yousaf', password : 'pass'}])
const [found, setFound] =  React.useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{localStorage.setItem('array',JSON.stringify(array))},[array])

 const changeState = async() =>{
     await setFound(current => !current)
}

const submit = (event) =>{
    const obj = {}
    event.preventDefault();
    if(array.length === 0){ // Array is empty
        if((name === null || password === null)||(name === '' || password === '')){ //check if name and password are empty
            alert('Enter username and password')
            
        }else{  // not empty then store in localstorage
            localStorage.setItem('name', name);
            localStorage.setItem('password',password);
            obj.id = Math.random();
            obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
            obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
            setArray(array => [...array,obj])
            setName('');
            setPassword('')
            return alert('You are registered'); 
            
        }
    }
    else  // array not empty
    {
        for( let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
            if((name === null || password === null)||(name === '' || password === '')){ //check if name and password is empty
               return alert('Enter username and password')
            }else if(name === array[i].name){ // if it is matched then setFound is set to true
                 changeState();
            }
        }
        if(found){
           return alert('it is matched')
        }else{
            return alert('it is not found')
        }
    }}

return(
    <div>
        <div className = {classes.formWrapper}>
            <Paper elevation={3} className = {classes.paper} >
            <Typography variant="h5" style = {{ textAlign : 'center'}}>Register</Typography>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField id="username" className={classes.textfield}  value = {name} name = "username"  label="Username" onChange = {e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <TextField id="password" className={classes.textfield}  value = {password} name = "password"  label="Password" onChange = {e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                <br />
                <span className ={classes.span}><Link to="/">Sign In</Link></span>
                <br />
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {{width : '100%', marginTop : '10px'}} onClick = {submit} >Register </Button>
            </form>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    </div>

)
```

}

export default Register;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is no point to call `await setFound(current => !current)` because state update will run async anyway and there is no way to wait for state update using hooks unless you write your custom hook. You could use callback in old `setState` way. More info on the link below.

https://ysfaran.github.io/blog/post/0002-use-state-with-promise/

Secondly, your logic in `submit` method isn't right. I believe you are trying to register user and you want to make sure that new user `name` is unique and it doesn't exist in the `array` which is list of user objects. If that's the case you can update your logic in `submit` method as following.

```
const submit = (event) => {
    const obj = {};
    event.preventDefault();
    // Array is empty
    if (name === null || password === null || name === "" || password === "") {
      //check if name and password are empty
      alert("Enter username and password");
    } 
    else {
      if (array.some((x) => x.name === name)) alert("user already exists");
      else {
        // not empty then store in localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("name", name);
        localStorage.setItem("password", password);
        obj.id = Math.random();
        obj.name = localStorage.getItem("name");
        obj.password = localStorage.getItem("password");
        setArray((array) => [...array, obj]);
        setName("");
        setPassword("");
        alert("successfully registred");
      }
    }
  };
```

So first `if` statement will ensure that name and password are provided. Then in `else` statement first `if` check will ensure that user with same `name` doesn't already exist in the array. You can call `changeState` instead of `alert` if you prefer but I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achive by setting `setFound` to either `true` or `false`.